# Need Some Quick Help With Preg_Replace :) Please :)

Tags: php

so this is the issue I'm having.
I want to remove this:

```
[quote="RANDOMTHING"]
```

Inside the "" could be literarly anything

plus I want to remove

```
[/quote]
```

How can I do this with preg_replace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to escape the `[` and use a placeholder (a character class as below, or `.*?` for anything or `\w+` for just letters) for the string in quotes:

```
$str = preg_replace('~
    \[/quote\]                    # either that
    |                             # or
    \[quote="[^\]"]+"\]           # with ="RANDOMTHING"
   ~x',
   '',
   $str
);
```

(You can remove the comments and linebreaks to compact it into one line. Just for illustration.)

Also check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there-anything-like-regexbuddy-in-the-open-source-world if you frequently run into regex questions, but don't know yet how they work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$var = preg_replace('/(\[quote="[^"]+"\])|(\[/quote\]/)', '', $var);
```

Try that out. Added parenthesis for easier reading.